# Replacing Spaces in a macro variable value with the quotes with space

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to replace space between variables passed in a macro variable with double quotes with space, i.e. " ". Please find below the code I am using for the same and the result I am getting.

```
%let str7=ABC DEF UVW XYZ;

%let str8 = %qsysfunc(quote(%qsysfunc(tranwrd(%qsysfunc(compbl(%qsysfunc(strip(%upcase(&str7.))))),%str( ),%nrstr(%")))));

%put ^^^^&str8;
```

The Log Displays:

> 18         %put ^^^^&str8;
>
> ^^^^"ABC""DEF""UVW""XYZ"

I need this to be "ABC" "DEF" "UVW" "XYZ".

I have also tried the following...

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;

    function delimit_words(iString $) $;    
    result = '"' || tranwrd(cats(compbl(iString))," ", '" ,"') || '"';    
    return (result );
    endsub;

run;


%let x =   A  B  C   ;
%let y = %sysfunc(delimit_words(&x));
%put &y;
```

but it gives me following error...

ERROR: The DELIMIT_WORDS function referenced in the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not found.

I have used the following approach given by Jeff.

```
   data test;
   id =1; _var="ABC"; output;
   id =1; _var="DEF"; output;
   id =1; _var="UVW"; output;
   id =2; _var="UVW"; output;
   id =3; _var="ABC"; output;
   id =3; _var="UVW"; output;
   id =3; _var="XYZ"; output;
   id =4; _var="ABC"; output;
   id =4; _var="XYZ"; output;
run;

%macro __test1(_byvar=, _qnam=, _id=);
    proc sort data= test out=_test;
        by &_byvar.;

  %if %superq(_qnam) ne %then
  %do; 
            %let __tmpmv_qnam = %qsysfunc(prxchange(%bquote(s/\b/"/),-1,%bquote(&_qnam))); 
            *";
            %put ^^^^^&__tmpmv_qnam.;
      where upcase(&_id) in (&__tmpmv_qnam);
  %end;

    run;

%mend;

%__test1 (_byvar=id ,_qnam = ABC UVW, _id=_var);
```

The log diaplayed following error:

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable _QNAM resolves to ABC UVW  
ERROR: Literal contains unmatched quote.
```

Please help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without debugging either of your approaches above, I can offer a third:

```
%let str8 = %sysfunc(prxchange(%bquote(s/\b/"/),-1,%quote(&str7.)));
*";
```

The `prxchange()` function tells SAS to replace every word boundary (`\b`) with a `"`.  As far as when to use `bquote()`, vs `quote()`, it's all documented online, but honestly I usually resort to trial and error.

The `*";` does nothing, but it makes things look nicer if your editor's syntax highlighting gets confused by the single quote (like mine does).

Comment: Thanks for a tidier approach, but it gives me following error.  ERROR: Literal contains unmatched quote.

Comment: I had a typo, now fixed (buote instead of quote).  Sorry about that.

Comment: proc sort data= &SUPPDS. out=_&_SUPPDS.;
    by &_byvar.;

    %if %superq(_qnam) ne %then
    %do;
       %let __tmpmv_n_qnam = %eval(%sysfunc(countw(%superq(_qnam),%str( ))));
           
    %if &__tmpmv_n_qnam gt 1 %then %do;
      %let __tmpmv_qnam = %sysfunc(prxchange(%bquote(s/\b/"/),-1,%quote(&_qnam.))); *";
    %end;
    %else %if &__tmpmv_n_qnam eq 1 %then %do;
      %let __tmpmv_qnam = %qsysfunc(quote(%qsysfunc(strip(%upcase(&_qnam.)))));
    %end;
    where upcase(&_id) in (&__tmpmv_qnam);
    %end;

 run;

Comment: I have updated my macro as per your approach. But it still gives me error. I have updated my post to describe the same. Please help.

Comment: That will split words at periods and other "word" boundaries and not just at spaces.  Try it is `%let str7=ABC D.EF;`

Answer (score 1):

Your `FCMP` works fine if you add the line

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;
```

to your code, if you're running in SAS 9.3 or later.

In general, the best approach is not to do this: instead create the macro variable with quotes in the first place.  How did you create this?  If you created it from a dataset, for example, you could have done:

```
proc sql;
  select quote(strip(name)) into :varlist separated by ','
  from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

which returns

> "Alfred","Alice","Barbara","Carol","Henry","James","Jane","Janet","Jeffrey","John","Joyce","Judy"
>   ,"Louise","Mary","Philip","Robert","Ronald","Thomas","William"

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to use double quotes then I think you are working way too hard.

```
%let str7=ABC DEF UVW XYZ;
%let str8="%sysfunc(tranwrd(&str7,%str( )," "))";
```

Now if your original string is not well formed and might contain multple spaces between words then you will first need to use `%COMPBL()` to clean it up.

```
%let str8=%sysfunc(compbl(&str7));
%let str8="%sysfunc(tranwrd(&str8,%str( )," "))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%let str7=ABC DEF UVW XYZ;

%let str8 ="%bquote(%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(strip(&str7.)),%str( ),%nrstr(%",%"))))";

%put ^^^^&str8;
```